# How to plot a graph with time on axis

Tags: python, canvas, time, pyqt5, axis

I am trying to write some code to plot some values in real time, I found below example and it works, but I want to show times on axis 12:30:20, 12:30:21..... instead of showing 10, 20, 30.

Is there any solution or where can I read about it?

```
import sys
import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        n_data = 50
        self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(n_data)]
        self.update_plot()

        self.show()

        # Setup a timer to trigger the redraw by calling update_plot.
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot(self):
        # Drop off the first y element, append a new one.
        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        self.canvas.axes.cla()  # Clear the canvas.
        self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
        # Trigger the canvas to update and redraw.
        self.canvas.draw()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the values you want on your `xdata`, something like this:

```
import sys
import random
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.xdata = ["12:30:20", "12:30:21", "12:30:22", "12:30:23", "12:30:24"]
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in self.xdata]
        self.update_plot()

        self.show()

        # Setup a timer to trigger the redraw by calling update_plot.
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(500)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot(self):
        # Drop off the first y element, append a new one.
        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        self.canvas.axes.cla()  # Clear the canvas.
        self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
        # Trigger the canvas to update and redraw.
        self.canvas.draw()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

that will produce this:
[image]

---

You can use any values you want there, here is another example with letters:

```
        self.xdata = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in self.xdata]
```

[image]

---

Here is a version from the followup question in the comments.
If you want the `xdata` to change you need to do the same you did for `ydata`

```
import sys
import random
import datetime
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def now(self, x):
        n = datetime.datetime.now()
        return (n + datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.xdata = [self.now(-5), self.now(-4), self.now(-3), self.now(-2), self.now(-1)]
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in self.xdata]
        self.update_plot()
        self.show()

        # Setup a timer to trigger the redraw by calling update_plot.
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.timer.start()

    def update_plot(self):
        # Drop off the first element, append a new one.
        self.xdata = self.xdata[1:] + [self.now(0)]
        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        self.canvas.axes.cla()  # Clear the canvas.
        self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
        # Trigger the canvas to update and redraw.
        self.canvas.draw()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Dear Helder, is there other way to show real times on axis? datetime.now(), time.time(). One signal or value in and plot with exact time.

Comment: I want to use like as below, but there is error. self.xdata.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f'))
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in self.xdata]
        self.update_plot()

Comment: Yes you can use that... take a look at my last addition, I added a new function now that helps you add multiple real time values on the X axis

Comment: Dear Helder, Thank you. Now it works as what I wanted.

Comment: @Esc I'm glad it works for you ... looks like you are new asking questions, you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes, I am new for programming.